# What is the purpose of the cache?

Tags: cache

I am using a phone with limited internal memory, and I noticed that my app cache has swelled up to 130 MB. What are the pros and cons of deleting the cache for certain apps? I don't understand what the cache is used for in the first place. Could someone explain?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the app cache"? There are lots of caches in Android and Android apps, so you'll get a better answer if you can be more specific. Just describe where you saw this 130 MB figure if you're not sure.

Comment: The 130MB figure comes from the folder named "Cached Data" under the internal memory. I was assuming that this is the sum total of all the caches of all the apps, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Cache**:-Its a temporary storage file used by websites as well as the applications to store some data on your device.

Cache memory contains references(where to store the settings i.e. in which folder it should load or store the source file ), thumbnails(images to be displayed in the application) etc.

**Advantages of Cache:-**

1.Once you have already loaded the application then your application loads exceptionally fast when compared to the first time load.(Apps like browser will load your websites much faster as they are stored in your cache)

2.Instead of the application loading the wallpaper from the source(Phone memory) every time you load the application it will create a buffer memory from which it can directly load the wallpaper saving the processor of the phone from doing this task.

**Disadvantages:-**

1.The website takes some time to load the requested page as there's no buffer memory. This is not much big disadvantage as for the second time the page will load fast.

2.Although your pages are loading fast or the application is responding faster there is limited storage space which the Cache memory can store. Once it get's filled / is nearing to then other application/same application will get slow as there's no space for the application to operate.

Answer (score 0):

On my GS3 I looked under running apps and selected show cashed processes
On clicking on one of them it gives the following description

```
Old application process kept for better speed in case it is needed again
```

I can only assume from this that cache is storing certain data when an app is first ran, so by deleting the data the app will run from new each time